# NSUserNotification customisable app icon?

Tags: macos, cocoa, itunes, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

I just noticed that iTunes' notification icon was replaced by album covers:

[image: iTunes Notification]

And it's app icon was a small one near the title, which is a bit different from the ones I knew of:

[image: Normal Notification]

Where I can only add images as part of the content, not the app icon.

Is there an undocumented `NSUserNotification` API that I didn't know?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NVM, I found the answer.

iTunes use private APIs.

```
NSUserNotification *notification = [NSUserNotification new];
[notification setValue:anImage forKey:@"_identityImage"];
```

Comment: is it possible to get approved by the store with this?

Comment: **PRIVATE** APIs are not allowed in MAS except Apple's in house apps.

Comment: I've submitted a radar asking Apple to make this public http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6424021574877184

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how exactly did you find out about this private API?

Comment: @Palleas class-dump on a Foundation framework binary.